# Digital signature for pdf document

Tags: digital-signature

I have pdf documents generated by our software.
Is there a way or program that I can call a program  from our software and sent it the name of document and folder location and this program will digitally sign the document.

Thanks,

Sol

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add the digital signature to PDF documents programmatically, you can try **GroupDocs.Signature** for .NET/Java. You will have to provide the document's path and the digital signature options to sign the document, as described in the following code snippets.

**C#:**

```
SignatureConfig Config = new SignatureConfig();
//set the storage path - folder that contains the PDF document
Config.StoragePath = "D:\\storage\\"; 
// instantiating the signature handler
var Handler = new SignatureHandler(Config);
// setup digital signature options
var SignOptions = new PdfSignDigitalOptions("acer.pfx", "sign.png");
SignOptions.SignAllPages = true;
SignOptions.HorizontalAlignment = Domain.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
SignOptions.VerticalAlignment = Domain.VerticalAlignment.Top;
// sign document
var SignedFilePath = Handler.Sign<string>("Sample.pdf", SignOptions, new SaveOptions { OutputType = OutputType.String });
```

**Java:**

```
// setup Signature configuration
SignatureConfig signConfig = new SignatureConfig(); 
signConfig.setStoragePath("D:\\Storage\\");
// instantiate handler
SignatureHandler<String> handler = new SignatureHandler<String>(signConfig);
// setup digital signature options
PdfSignDigitalOptions signOptions = new PdfSignDigitalOptions("acer.pfx", "sign.png");
signOptions.setDocumentPageNumber(1);
// set options for the output
SaveOptions saveOptions = new SaveOptions();
saveOptions.setOutputType(OutputType.String);
saveOptions.setOutputFileName("signed_output.pdf");
// sign document
String signedPath = handler.<String>sign("Sample.pdf", signOptions, saveOptions);
```

*Disclosure: I work as Developer Evangelist at GroupDocs.*